# Issue on reset on RingCounter in Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, counter, reset

Well I keep having this problem on many modules and it never bothered me as I was just experimenting. However now I am trying to be 100% correct so... I have this ring counter for example and I feed the ouput on 8 leds out of an FPGA. Alright, it works as a charm but reset condition is faulty. When I feed the binary on the FPGA it starts correct from MSB=1 and the rest of bits are 0. However when I press reset the led pattern just freezes and continues operation when I release button. The problem in some modules was that I foolishly had the same reset for counter and clock so it was obvious why this was heppening. However now I just drive it from another pulldown resistor button and keep having this issue.

```
module Ringcounter # ( parameter LENGTH = 8) (
input clk, rst,
output [LENGTH-1:0]q
    );
reg [LENGTH-1:0] f;
genvar i;
for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i = i+1) 
assign q[i]=f[i];

always @ (posedge clk)begin
if (rst) begin f[LENGTH-1]=1'b1; f[LENGTH-2:0]=0; end
else
f={f[0],f[LENGTH-1:1]};
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use synchronous reset, thus reset high will only be effective on the following clock positive edge.

Why do you need this `for` here? Consider the following:

```
module Ringcounter # ( parameter LENGTH = 8) (
input wire clk,
input wire rst,
output reg [LENGTH-1:0] f
);

always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (rst) begin f[LENGTH-1] <= 1'b1; f[LENGTH-2:0] <= 0; end
    else
        f <= {f[0],f[LENGTH-1:1]};
end

endmodule
```

Note changed I made: (1) removed q completely, instead outputting f as register; (2) changed blocking assignments to non-blocking ones.

Edit: ok, if you do not like output reg, then the following:

```
module Ringcounter # ( parameter LENGTH = 8) (
input wire clk,
input wire rst,
output wire [LENGTH-1:0] q
);

reg [LENGTH-1:0] f;
assign q [LENGTH-1:0]  = f[LENGTH-1:0];

always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (rst) begin f[LENGTH-1] <= 1'b1; f[LENGTH-2:0] <= 0; end
    else
        f <= {f[0],f[LENGTH-1:1]};
end

endmodule
```

but it changes nothing, result is the same.

If such modification will not help, then you, most probably, simply stop clock when reset is active.

Comment: I have a habit of not directly putting on ouput blocks that I make computations with. Isnt asychronus reset a no no when it comes on designing modules?

Comment: I rechecked my ucf and it seems that I mistakingly named the same name on the 2 reset pulldown buttons I have. I must say that this must be the problem overally as I am reusing the same ucf file thank you very much

However I must say that ISE doesnt like this 

 'assign q [LENGTH-1:0]  = f[LENGTH-1:0];'

and throws an error during synthesis.

Comment: Right, I corrected my mistake. I initially declared array as unpacked. Next time when you talk about errors, it would be good if you put here which exactly error you get, otherwise people have to guess what is going on at your end.

Comment: Technically you should put the `assign` statement after `f` is declared, otherwise you will get some weird issues in some software - e.g. ModelSim will error out from duplicate declarations (`f` gets implicitly defined as a single bit wire by the `assign` and then redefined as a `reg`).

Comment: @TomCarpenter Agreed, modified answer.